# ionic tap (delay click)

Tags: cordova, touch, ionic-framework

i'm working on phonegap project with ionic framework.
i create a simple project and add android platform, then add a button and run the project on real device.
in result, tapping a button (click speed) on a button (running in samsung with android ver.4) need touch button about 500ms> and it isn't applicable.

even i use fastclick.js, but touch time yet is not applicable, it's too high.

any one can help me ?

best regards,
mreza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually, any short tab and touch fired and run, but no visual effect appears on screen.
so, following link is useful to fix visual effect:
http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/no-visual-feedback-on-quick-taps/7280

Answer (score 4):

Basically, the browser waits roughly 300ms to see if the user is double-tapping, or just tapping on the display once. **Ionic automatically removes the 300ms delay** in order to make Ionic apps feel more "native" like. **Fastclick** and **Angular's ngTouch** should not be included, to avoid conflicts.

Some browsers already remove the delay with certain settings, such as the CSS property touch-events: none or with specific meta tag viewport values. However, each of these browsers still handle clicks differently, such as when to fire off or cancel the event (like scrolling when the target is a button, or holding a button down). For browsers that already remove the 300ms delay, consider Ionic's tap system as a way to normalize how clicks are handled across the various devices so there's an expected response no matter what the device, platform or version. Additionally, Ionic will prevent ghostclicks which even browsers that remove the delay still experience.

Comment: ok, but either not work or in not enough fast,
when i touch a simple button, i must hold touch on button 500ms> to apply. really it is not tap, it's holding.
i need detect tap like other apps button. simple and short tap.

Comment: To detect holding on button, use `on-hold` directive. You can also set your gesture.

Comment: i don't want to get hold action. i need get tap, but for tapping, user must hold touch about 500ms. fast tap not detected. :(

Comment: no, ionic does not do it automatically in all cases, like swiping

Answer (score 2):

use of 'data-tap-disabled="true"' on element, fixed my problem.
'http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/page/tap/'